# PHP/MSSQL Present stored field value in a drop-down list

Tags: php, pdo

I use the following code to create a number of drop-down lists with the same values. The values are brought in from an MSSQL table via a query written elsewhere.

```
<?php
 $select = '';
 while($row = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH))
 {
   $select .= "<option value='".$row['Code']."'>".$row['Code']."</option> ";
 }
 echo "<select name=\"proj1[]\">";
 echo $select;
 echo "</select>";
?>
```

The user makes his selections, then submits the form and the record is written to the PROJECTS table in the PROJ DB (fields: Proj1, Proj2, Proj3, Proj4). The original drop-down values are held in a separate table (CODES). When the record is called up in a browser, a prepared SELECT statement runs against PROJECTS to load it. I would like to show the user the drop-down selections he made when the completed form is loaded, i.e., the values of Proj1-Proj4 for a given record in PROJECTS. How can I do this? I'm not sure where to put my 'option selected'.

Comment: You need to show how/where you are getting the current DB value that the user previously selected.

Comment: @AbraCadaver: I've edited the question. Hope I've provided enough detail.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help

```
 $select = '';
    while($row = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH))
    {
        $select .= "<option value='".$row['Code']."' '".$row['Code'] == $_POST['proj1'] ? ' selected="selected"' : ''."'  >".$row['Code']."</option> ";
    }
    echo "<select name=\"proj1[]\">";
    echo $select;
    echo "</select>";
```